# Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers not working in MVC 6 Razor View

Tags: razor, asp.net-core-mvc

Good Day People,
I'm having a strange issue in my Mvc6 project.
For some reason, since i did the VS2015 Update 3 my @addTagHelper isnt being recognized.

[image]

Resulting in the issue seen below

[image]

Ive tried various solutions found online but none have worked. Most commonly people say that that Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers should be added to the project.json file, which i have done...

[image]

Im banging my head against the wall with this issue as i honestly dont know what else to do...
Any help will be greatly appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that it was resharper causing this issue. To fix it all i had to do was exclude .cshtml from the resharper list.

To do this click on Resharper in VS tab, select Options. Navigate to Code Inspection and select Settings. Add *.cshtml to the File Masks box on the bottom right of the screen. Click save and all Tag Helper errors should be gone.